# Multiple network interfaces and airmon-ng

Tags: networkmanager, network-interface, internet, aircrack-ng

Before using `airmon-ng` on a network interface, you now have to do :

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

This is essential in order to be able to put any interface in monitor mode, but it stops the service network-manager.

As a result, having two network interfaces, i can't use the other interface for "normal" internet use because network-manager is off. But if i turn it on again, then the first one goes out of monitor mode.

Is there a workaround to solve this problem ? How can i use one wireless interface for "normal" internet and use the `aircrack-ng` suite with the other?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to manually connect to the access point via these commands. Assuming your essid is 'home', your password is password123, your network uses WPA and your wireless card is wlan0.

```
 ipconfig wlan0 up
 wpa_passphrase home >> /etc/wpa.conf
 wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa.conf
 dhclient wlan0
```

If you want to reconnect after this initial setup,  just run the wpa_supplicant and the dhclient commands again.